# Cannot connect zapier to ghost

Tags: integration

Basically, zapier asks for Admin API URL and Admin API Key. [Zapier Integration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8JVY.png) In ghost admin area I cannot find Admin API Key. I am using ghost Version 2.14.3.

How do I connect ghost to zapier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating ghost to Version 2.25.9 solved this problem!